# Chip: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components-android, android-chips

I want to add a Chip view to ChipGroup in my project but always I get below error

My code in Activity

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
      Chip chip = new Chip(getApplicationContext());
      chip.setText(names.get(i));
      chip.setId(i);
      chipGroup.addView(chip);
    }
```

and Error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:81)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable.loadFromAttributes(ChipDrawable.java:334)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(ChipDrawable.java:276)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:193)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:186)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:182)
```

My app theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   
  </style>
```

As shown in the code above my theme is right!

Answer (score 4):

After a while I found that need to pass **Activity** to Chip instead pass *context*

The code is right below.

```
 Chip chip = new Chip(this);
```